# jQuery lazyload works only on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading, jquery-lazyload

I am using jquery lazyload on one of my pages, and it seems to not be working on window scroll but only on window resize.

The images doesn't appear on scroll, but if I resize the window the images appear.

I noticed that if I delete this css rule;

```
html,body{
  height: 100%;
}
```

it works, but I really need this for other stuff.

Another question, is this script cross browser? I was looking for the browser compatibility, but I can't find anything.

Comment: What does your HTML and JavaScript look like? And can you link to the jQuery plugin?

Comment: i am sorry, I am using this plugin https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.lazyload/1.9.1/jquery.lazyload.min.js. 

my javascript is like the reference example
  $(function() {
     $("img.lazy").lazyload({
         effect : "fadeIn",
         failure_limit : 10
     });

  });

the html is a bootstrap page very long, with  this code
html,body{
  height: 100%;
}
if i delete this code, the lazy load works, but without this I lost other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Please reference https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.lazyload/1.9.1/jquery.lazyload.min.js. Settings of LazyLoad event is already set to scroll.

Comment: I know, but my problem it is that on scroll doesn't work.
It works only if a do manually the resize of the window.

Comment: I found this code that maybe fix this problem, but I am not completely sure that this will bring other problems 


$("html,body").on('scroll', function(){ 
    $(window).resize();
});

Answer (score 0):

Triggering a resize event on scroll can produce a performance nightmare as soon as you have scripts included which react on resize.

I recommend [lazysizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/). It simply works always in every environment without any configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it was the overflow: hidden on the body tag.
thanks anyway.
Someone knows the browser compability for jquery.lazyload?
I can't find if it is a cross-browser script